# Having issue with aggregation in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using MongoDb with Node.js. And I'm having trouble with aggregation.This is the Example of data in Collection in Database:

```
{
 "name": "abcdef",
 "address": ghijk,
 "reli":"A",
 "prov:"a" ,
}

{
"name": "xyz",
 "address": "vwz",
 "reli":"B",
 "prov:"b" ,
}

{
"name": "qwe",
 "address": "rty",
 "reli":'C',
 "prov:"c" ,
},
 {
 "name": "abcdef",
 "address": ghijk,
 "reli":"A",
 "prov:"a" ,
}
{
"name": "hat",
 "address": "ate",
 "reli":'C',
 "prov:"c" ,
},
```

This is my query to count:

```
const count = await db.aggregate([
    {
      $facet: {
        "reli": [
          { $group: { _id: '$reli', count: { $sum: 1 } } }
        ],
        "prov": [
          { $group: { _id: '$prov', count: { $sum: 1 } } }
        ],
```

This is my **result** of the **query**:

```
  [
    {
        "reli": [
            {
                "_id": "A",
                "count": 2
            },
            {
                "_id": "B",
                "count": 1
            },
            {
            "_id": "C",
            "count": 2
             }
    "prov": [
            {
                "_id": "a",
                "count": 2
            },
            {
                "_id": "b",
                "count": 1
            },
            {
            "_id": "c",
            "count": 2
             }

}]
```

I want to aggregate this data. And only want **values** for every **reli** and **prov** and it's **count** in my results.

**Expecting Output:**

```
    [
    
    "reli":{
    
    A:2  // As my Collection has 2 "A" And 2 is it's count
    C:2  // As there is 2 "C" in Collection.

    }

    "prov":{
    c:2 //As there are 2 "c" in Collection. 
    b:1 //As there are 1 "b" in Collection
     }
]
```

Comment: can you please share your aggregation query  and explain where you are facing issue

Comment: Query added above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$arrayToObject` to get what you want here, creating keys from your values. For example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      reli: [
        {$group: { _id: "$reli", v: {$sum: 1}}},
        {$project: {v: 1, k: "$_id", _id: 0}}
      ],
      prov: [
        {$group: {_id: "$prov", v: {$sum: 1}}},
        {$project: {v: 1, k: "$_id", _id: 0}}
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      prov: {$arrayToObject: "$prov"},
      reli: {$arrayToObject: "$reli"}
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j7MVWK8npdq)

If there is a correlation between the `reli` and `prov` group, as in your example, you can avoid the `$facet`, group once, count once and only project twice.

Comment: Error :`MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $arrayToObject requires an object with keys 'k' and 'v'. Missing either or both keys from: {_id: "2", k: "2"}`

Comment: Actually there is no corelation between `reli` and `prov`.

Comment: The error you got means you missed the `v` in the `$group`. Please see the playground example that I attached to the original answer, to see how it works. It allows you to follow it step by step using the steps 'drop-down' list

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use `$group` like this, the output isn't exactly like expected, but it may help you :

```js
const reli = await db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$reli', 
      'count': {
        '$sum': 1
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      '_id': 0, 
      'reli': '$_id', 
      'count': 1
    }
  }
])

const prov = await db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$prov', 
      'count': {
        '$sum': 1
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      '_id': 0, 
      'prov': '$_id', 
      'count': 1
    }
  }
])

const res = {
  reli,
  prov
};
```

**output** :

```json
{
  "prov": [
    { "count": 2, "prov": "a" },
    { "count": 1, "prov": "b" },
    { "count": 2, "prov": "c" }
  ],
  "reli": [
    { "count": 2, "reli": "A" },
    { "count": 2, "reli": "C" },
    { "count": 1, "reli": "B" }
  ]
}
```

From this data, if you need it, you could re write key:value, for exact data model as you asked.

Comment: I've already done this in a single query. All I need is to get Output like **Expected Output**.